# Python - test all values in array against scalar value

Tags: arrays, testing, numpy

I am trying to compare values in a numpy array with a scalar value.
Here is an example of this array. If it's any help it can only contain positive values.

```
y = np.array([ 1 , 0.008 , 3 , 4 , 5])
```

In another section of my code I want to compare this array with a scalar, say 3.5 in an 'if' statement used to break while loop.
I want to test if ANY of the values in the array is larger then this scalar value.

```
while True:

    if any_value_in_array(y) > 3.5
       break

    #random code
```

Any command that would enable me of doing something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `any()` on the condition check

```
In [377]: (y > 3.5).any()
Out[377]: True
```

---

Longer Example

```
In [378]: y
Out[378]: array([ 1.   ,  0.008,  3.   ,  4.   ,  5.   ])

In [379]: (y > 3.5)
Out[379]: array([False, False, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)

In [380]: (y > 3.5).any()
Out[380]: True
```

Additionally, if you want to check if all elements match the condition, you could use `all()`